# gulp-watch doesn't triggered when create or deleted file

Tags: html, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

dude ... my gulp doesn't triggered when i create new file or deleted

this is my simple code

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./src"
  });
  gulp.watch("./src/sass/**/*.sass", {cwd:'./'}, ['sass']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./src/js/**/*.js", {cwd:'./'}, ['javascript']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html", {cwd:'./'}, ['html']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

it works

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./src"
  });
  gulp.watch("./src/**/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve'], function () {
  gulp.watch('/project_path_task', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    gulp.start('your_task_like_sass_js_or_html');
  });
});
```